# Fill null value with random value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill null values in my continuous variables column with random numbers. I tried the code below but can't seem to get the null values to be filled with a random number. Any thoughts?

```
df.mask(np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p=[.2,.8]))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (but not optimal) is to create a dataframe with the same shape and index/columns labels then use `fillna`:

```
df = df.fillna(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(df.shape),
                            index=df.index, columns=df.columns))
```

Comment: This definitely worked to fill the null values however when I graphed the original dataset (with null) vs. new dataset (with null filled with random value) to compare how closely the original and new dataset matched up - the new data set with the random values did not closely resemble the original data set. Is there a way to have it match up more closely?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you update your post with a sample of two dataframes please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever tried [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#:%7E:text=Fill%20NA%2FNaN%20values%20using%20the%20specified%20method.&text=Value%20to%20use%20to%20fill,DataFrame%20will%20not%20be%20filled.) ?

Following the doc's page, let's create a df with nulls:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                   [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                   [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                  columns=list("ABCD"))
```

df output:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4
```

Then, I can fill the missing values with::

```
np.random.seed(42)

df.fillna(np.random.random())
```

Note: If you want to have reproducible code, it is good to seed the [random number](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/numpy-random?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaignid=14989519638&utm_adgroupid=127836677279&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1001625).

the new df with missings filled up

```
        A         B         C  D
0  0.950714  2.000000  0.950714  0
1  3.000000  4.000000  0.950714  1
2  0.950714  0.950714  0.950714  5
3  0.950714  3.000000  0.950714  4
```